# htaccess redirect not including filename in destination

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using an htaccess rewrite that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^library/.*(\.pdf)$ email/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The problem is, the redirect works but does not contain the filename of the file being redirected:

```
http://mydomain.com/library/.pdf
```

Is there something wrong with the way I'm setting up the rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^library/(.*)\.pdf$ email/$1 [L,R=301]`

if you want just the name, otherwise

`RewriteRule ^library/(.*)\.pdf$ email/$1.pdf [L,R=301]`

for the full name

Comment: you edited your answer before I could finish typing my response requesting the edit. Thanks!